# How to display the time in a jpanel while a background thread is running?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm trying to display the time in a jpanel while a background thread performs an expensive operation. Obviously the time thread should get a higher priority than the background thread to display the time accurately.

I've written the following solution, but I'm sure it can be done better. What are your suggestions ?

Also: How do I shut down the background thread correctly without using .stop() ?

Edit: After having tested the program without priority settings it also works, but I don't really know why.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test1 extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int time = 23*3600+59*60+30;

    private Thread operationThread; 

    public Test1(){                 
        JLabel text = new JLabel();

        Timer timeDisplayer = new Timer(1000, e -> {
            //Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            text.setText((time/3600)%24+":"+(time/60)%60+":"+(time%60));
            time+=1;
        });
        timeDisplayer.setInitialDelay(0);                

        JButton b = new JButton("Restart operation");
        b.addActionListener(arg0 -> makeNewThread());               

        add(b);
        add(text);

        timeDisplayer.start();
    }

    private void makeNewThread(){
        if(operationThread!=null && operationThread.isAlive())
            operationThread.stop();
        operationThread = new Thread(() -> {
            //Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            //expensiveOperation();     
        });
        operationThread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        f.setLocation(400,50);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(100,100);
        f.setContentPane(t);
        f.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

Comment: _Obviously the time thread should get a higher priority..._  Decisions about thread priorities are not always obvious.  How precise do you need the time display to be?  Remember, all you're doing is displaying it on the screen.

Comment: Also, beware premature optimization.  Are you asking this question because you've already tried it, and the result was not satisfactory?  Or are you trying to anticipate a problem that may or may not exist?

Comment: Don't assume that the accuracy of the `Timer` or `Thread`, none of these every guarantee that the amount of time they wait is exact, only that it will be "at least" the given amount of time.  Use an anchor value and calculate the amount of time that has past

Comment: The program as is works how I want it to work, I'm just curious if this is a good approach. And I don't understand why the background thread doesn't affect the Timer and how to shutdown the background thread without stop. @MadProgrammer so I should use System.currentTimeMillis() ?

Comment: Mad Physicist answered almost everything. But how to avoid stop() ?

Comment: Stopping a thread is a little black magic and relies on the content been executed in the thread to support things like interrupts and monitor flags. Controlling thread priority is actually an OS issue, as Java `Thread`s are actually OS threads, so on some platforms you might not be able to actually change the priority. *"should use System.currentTimeMillis()"* - It would be a more accurate measure of time ;)

Comment: @user. I addressed the second part of your question in an edit. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, things that you display (e.g. a timer), do not have to refresh that fast to get something that is visually appealing. A one second delay is a huge amount of time in computer time, so it is not necessary to give the timer update thread extra priority.

Your usage if the [swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class can be improved significantly. The way the timer works is to fire an `ActionEvent` to your handler, which is queued up on the the event-dispatching thread. This means that there can be a delay between the event firing and the execution of your listener. A better way to handle that is to store the value of [`System.currentTimeMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) somewhere and use it in your callback:

```
...

private long startMillis;

public Test1()
{
    ...

    Timer timeDisplayer = new Timer(1000, e -> {
        time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis + 500L) / 1000L;
        text.setText(((time / 3600) % 24) + ":" + ((time / 60) % 60) + ":" + (time % 60));
    });
    timeDisplayer.setInitialDelay(0);

    ...

    startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    timeDisplayer.start();
}
```

This has the additional advantage that you can speed up your timer as much as you want, add sub-second precision, etc. If you do decide to do that, it may be better to delay the time computation as much as possible, e.g., by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of the component displaying the time.

As far as stopping the thread goes, I suggest a simple interrput-based mechanism to avoid using the deprecated `stop()` method. Rather than using `stop()`, use [`interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) on the expensive computation thread. This will generally (but read the docs) do one of two things:

1. Throw an interrupted exception in the computation thread.
2. Set the thread's interrupt status.

It is then your computation's job to respond to both of those cases. Usually, you would enclose the expensive part in a try-catch block and make attempts to check interrupt status periodically. Here is an example:

```
private expensiveOperation()
{
    try {
        for(SomeObject among : millionsOfItems) {
            // Do stuff
            if(Thread.currentThread().interrupted()) {
                // Possibly log the interruption as you would for the exception
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
        // Probably just ignore or log it somehow since this is really a normal condition
    } finally {
        // If your thread needs special cleanup, this is the place to put it
        // This block will be triggered by exceptions as well as breaks
    }
}
```

You can check the interrupt flag for a thread using either [`interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) or [`isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted--). The only real difference between them is that the former clears the interrupt status when it checks, while the latter does not. If you just want to make a one-off check and let the thread die, it does not really matter which one you use.

The advantage of this mechanism is that it gives you a lot more control than calling `stop()`, especially if your thread requires special cleanup.